# Github not letting me to use my php script to send email form, what to do

Tags: php, github, client-side, backend

I've been googling and but none of the answers meet my need...
I read that Github wouldnt let me use POST method so i changed it to GET method but it doesnt fix the problem, then i read about github not letting people to use php form due to the danger of spams. Is there any other way that i can let people write stuff to me from my website hosted on GitHub?

So I made a php file to let people send me email from my website http://simonykhsu.com

this is my PHP code:

```
    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {



    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

    $email_to = "simonizerlol@gmail.com";

    $email_subject = "From simonykhsu.com";





    function died($error) {

        // your error code can go here

        echo "I am very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

        echo $error."<br /><br />";

        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

        die();

    }



    // validation expected data exists

        if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['email']) ||

        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||

        !isset($_POST['message'])) {

        died('I am sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       

    }



    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required

    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required

    $comments = $_POST['message']; // required



    $error_message = "";

    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

      if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

      if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

      if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

      if(strlen($comments) < 2) {

    $error_message .= 'The message you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

      if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    died($error_message);

  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }



    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";





// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>



<!-- include your own success html here -->



Thank you for contacting me. I will be in touch with you very soon.



<?php

}

?>
```

this is my HTML code:

```
<form name = "emailme" action="messageme.php" method="GET" enctype="text/plain">
            <div class="section landing-section">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                            <a name="Contact">
                            <h2 class="text-center">Keep in touch?</h2>
                            <form class="contact-form">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label>First Name</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30" placeholder="First Name">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label>Last Name</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30"placeholder="Last Name">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label>Email</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30" placeholder="Email">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label>Telephone</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30" placeholder="Telephone(not required)">
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <label>Message</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="message" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="4" placeholder="Tell me your thoughts and feelings..."></textarea>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                                        <a href="messageme.php"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-lg btn-fill"> Send Message  </button></a>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: GitHub does not execute any of your code. To send an email, you need to execute some serverside code. The only option with GHPages is to ask some *other* server to do it for you, like Mandrill, but... I would not recommend clientside mail. Another alternative is to just open the email client and ask the user to send the email, using `mailto:` protocol.

Comment: that was what i did at first, but after reading this website http://www.html-form-guide.com/email-form/email-form-mailto.html
and understood the drawbacks, i thought it wont be a good idea because some of the browser doesnt support it

Comment: It's not a good idea. If you don't have a server, the best idea is to just leave your address on the webpage there and let people email you themselves. However, there's a places that you can get a semidecent server space for free, or peanuts. Try Googling for "free php hosting".